# Convert or output SSIS package/job to SQL script?

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, ssis

I understand this may be a little far-fetched, but is there a way to take an existing SSIS package and get an output of the job it's doing as T-SQL? I mean, that's basically what it is right? Transfering data from one database to another can be done with T-SQL as well.

I'm wondering this because I'm trying to get away from using SSIS packages for data transfer and instead using EF/linq to do this on the fly in my application. My thought process is that currently I have an SSIS package that transfers and formats data from one database to another in preparation to be spit out to an excel. This SSIS package runs nightly and helps speed up the generation of the excel as once the data is transferred to the second db, it's already nice and formatted correctly.

However, if I could leverage EF and maybe some linq to sql in order to format the data from the first database on the fly and spit it out to excel quickly without having to use this second db, that would be great. So can my original question be done, can I extract the t-sql representation of an SSIS package some how?

Comment: SSIS is a .NET application and not a SQL based solution. So No, you can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSIS packages are not exclusively T-SQL. They can consist of custom back-end code, file system changes, Office document creation steps, etc, to name only a few. As a result, generating the entirety of an SSIS package's work into T-SQL isn't possible, because the full breadth of it's work isn't limited to SQL Server.